# is there any way to assign variable for css claas name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking to assign variable names to css class dynamically.
Here im explaining with small code

```
#A1, #A2, #A3, #A4{
   float: left;
   clear: left;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 15px;
}
```

instead of writing " #A1, #A2, #A3, #A4" , i want to write some variable. with for loop i want to define four classes while page is getting loaded.

could you pls explain me how to do that?

Comment: There's no such thing as a CSS class, CSS has class selectors, HTML has classes and you are using ID selectors.

Comment: Why not just use a class selector and assign that class to all the elements with their ID, so they are styled based on their class the same and still have their unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [css class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)?

You can then use the jQuery [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method to assign to elements.

```
//apply class to all divs
$('div').addClass('someclass')

.someclass {
   float: left; 
   clear: left; 
   width: 300px; 
   margin: 15px; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but would have, because you are using JavaScript (jQuery on top of that) to solve a non-JavaScript problem, that should be solved server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You could always serve a PHP file as CSS.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/

Alternatively look at Less (either as rubygem or less.js) or SASS (also ruby)

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/